# CSLA performance

Tags: csla

I am new to CSLA, i just want to know what factors that could affect CSLA performance when loading records in a grid

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing inheritantly bad with the performance with CSLA and you should not see any additional issues by using CSLA.

A common trap that developers using CSLA can fall into is when it comes to parent/child relationships. The architecture may lead to more seperate database calls then would be necessary.

This is totally avoidable and can easily be avoided as long as you are vigilant of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think, choose the right stereotypes. for example if your grid is for displaying records only, you can use readOnlyListBase, with this it will not include states property such as isDirty, isNew and etc..

Answer (score 0):

The issue which may you may face is constant Daatabase calls bacause of Parent Child Relationsship. 
But, It can be avoided by creating a method in your repository which will act as Cache by fetchng the data accordingly at its first call to DB and store the fecthed data and use the those data for further child classes and prevent from further DB calls.